# Project euler 10 - [haskell] Why so inefficient?

Tags: haskell, primes, sieve-of-eratosthenes

Alright, so i've picked up project euler where i left off when using java, and i'm at problem 10. I use Haskell now and i figured it'd be good to learn some haskell since i'm still very much a beginner.

http://projecteuler.net/problem=10

My friend who still codes in java came up with a very straight forward way to implement the sieve of eratosthenes:

http://puu.sh/5zQoU.png

I tried implementing a better looking (and what i thought was gonna be a slightly more efficient) Haskell function to find all primes up to 2,000,000. 
I came to this very elegant, yet apparently enormously inefficient function:

```
primeSieveV2 :: [Integer] -> [Integer]
primeSieveV2 [] = []
primeSieveV2 (x:xs) = x:primeSieveV2( (filter (\n -> ( mod n x ) /= 0) xs) )
```

Now i'm not sure why my function is so much slower than his (he claim his works in 5ms), if anything mine should be faster, since i only check composites once (they are removed from the list when they are found) whereas his checks them as many times as they can be formed.

Any help?

Comment: Sieve of Eratosthenes?  5ms?  For all primes up to 2 million?  Sounds suspiciously fast to me.  It's semi-hard to get a computer to even *count* that fast, if you want to do anything else as well.

Comment: He's lying, unless he works in NSA, I doubt it though, he wouldn't be working on project euler if he was

Comment: If you only need numbers up to 2,000,000 then use Int instead of Integer.  And if you care about speed, use `rem` not `mod`.

Comment: Even if his takes a few seconds, mine takes over 28 seconds for all primes up to 100,000 !

Comment: yours is not the sieve.  It is brute force dividing the numbers.  His uses a vector of bools to implement the sieve yours returns arbitrary precision integers of the actual numbers. The results aren't even comparable.

Comment: There are still people who don't know about http://www.cs.hmc.edu/~oneill/papers/Sieve-JFP.pdf ? That should be required reading at this point..

Comment: That's a cool paper @Carl. I'll add it to http://eprints.whiterose.ac.uk/3784/1/runcimanc1.pdf for my list of required reading for primes in functional programming languages.

Comment: Your code does mod operations, which are very slow; a good sieve only does additions, which are very fast.

Answer (score 7):

You don't actually have a sieve here. In Haskell you could write a sieve as

```
import Data.Vector.Unboxed hiding (forM_)
import Data.Vector.Unboxed.Mutable
import Control.Monad.ST (runST)
import Control.Monad (forM_, when)
import Prelude hiding (read)

sieve :: Int -> Vector Bool
sieve n = runST $ do
  vec <- new (n + 1) -- Create the mutable vector
  set vec True       -- Set all the elements to True
  forM_ [2..n] $ \ i -> do -- Loop for i from 2 to n
    val <- read vec i -- read the value at i
    when val $ -- if the value is true, set all it's multiples to false
      forM_ [2*i, 3*i .. n] $ \j -> write vec j False
  freeze vec -- return the immutable vector

main = print . ifoldl' summer 0 $ sieve 2000000
  where summer s i b = if b then i + s else s
```

This "cheats" by using a mutable unboxed vector, but it's pretty darn fast

```
$ ghc -O2 primes.hs
$ time ./primes
  142913828923
  real: 0.238 s
```

This is about 5x faster than my benchmarking of augustss's solution.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could include short explanations to the "weird" lines. (Mostly the ones referring to ST and vector stuff.)

Comment: @kqr Updated with some documentation. It's very close to the Java code, Haskell makes a great imperative language

Comment: @jozefg And how does it compare to my simple prime generator?

Comment: @augustss Yours clocked in at `2.24` seconds. So it's approximately 5x faster yes?

Comment: Please note that the numbers zero and one are in fact not prime, so this for the sieve to be fully correct you would also have to cross off those before returning the vector. This would then also give you the correct sum of all primes to two million, namely 142913828922.

Answer (score 6):

To actually implement the sieve efficiently in Haskell you probably need to do it the Java way (i.e., allocate a mutable array an modify it).

For just generating primes I like this:

```
primes = 2 : filter (isPrime primes) [3,5 ..]
  where isPrime (p:ps) x = p*p > x || x `rem` p /= 0 && isPrime ps x
```

And then you can print the sum of all primes primes < 2,000,000

```
main = print $ sum $ takeWhile (< 2000000) primes
```

You can speed it up by adding a type signature `primes :: [Int]`.
But it works well with `Integer` as well and that also gives you the correct sum (which 32 bit Int will not).

See [The Genuine Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://www.cs.tufts.edu/~nr/cs257/archive/melissa-oneill/Sieve-JFP.pdf) for more information.

Comment: It's strange to claim a mutable array is necessary before linking to a paper that shows how to do it very efficiently without a mutable array.

Comment: I always wondered, is there a proof that p < x such that p*p > x always exists? isPrime relies on this to be true. Suppose the last _computed_ p is less than sqrt x. In order to find p such that p*p > x we might need to compute a p >= x. Yet, in this algorithm we won't know this, as (p:ps) needs the head to be available. Bummer. bottom.

Comment: There is in fact a prime between n and 2n, this is Bertrand's conjecture and was proven 1850.

Comment: I bet the mutable array is more efficient than the link I provided.

Comment: FYI, if you want to treat O'Neill's technique fairly, you should use a good implementation. The one in https://hackage.haskell.org/package/NumberSieves-0.1.2/docs/Math-Sieve-ONeill.html appears to be fairly careful, although I suspect it may be more efficient to represent the wheel as a vector than as a circular list.

Comment: It seems likely that a sufficiently good priority queue implementation (and unboxing almost everything, and maybe making the wheel a vector) could help it use the CPU cache more effectively than the mutable array technique. The priority queue usage pattern is a little weird, which makes me wonder if it might be good to use a weird structure like a search tree under the left-spine view (as described in, e.g., "Numerical Representations as Higher-Order Nested Datatypes" by Ralf Hinze).

Comment: @dfeuer Go ahead and experiment.  Actual performance is hard to guess.

Answer (score 1):

The time complexity of your code is *n<sup>2</sup>* (in *n* primes produced). It is impractical to run for producing more than first 10...20 thousand primes.

The main problem with that code is not that it uses `rem` but that it starts its filters prematurely, so creates too many of them. Here's how you fix it, with a *small* tweak:

```
{-# LANGUAGE PatternGuards #-}
primes = 2 : sieve primes [3..] 

sieve (p:ps) xs | (h,t) <- span (< p*p) xs = h ++ sieve ps [x | x <- t, rem x p /= 0]
                                               -- sieve ps (filter (\x->rem x p/=0) t)
main = print $ sum $ takeWhile (< 100000) primes
```

This improves the time complexity by about *n<sup>1/2</sup>* (in *n* primes produced) and gives it a drastic speedup: it gets to `100,000` 75x faster. Your ***28 seconds*** should become *~ 0.4 sec*. But, you probably tested it in GHCi as interpreted code, not compiled. Marking it<sup>1)</sup> as `:: [Int]` and compiling with `-O2` flag gives it another ~ 40x speedup, so it'll be ***~ 0.01 sec***. To reach `2,000,000` with this code takes ~ 90x longer, for a whopping ***~ 1 sec*** of projected run time.

<sup>1)</sup> be sure to use `sum $ map (fromIntegral :: Int -> Integer) $ takeWhile ...` in `main`.

see also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms#Empirical_orders_of_growth